# symfony - an action doesn't work

Tags: symfony1, routes, action

I've just created a module 'register', with an action called facebookRegister.
The routing configuration is:

```
register_facebook:
  url:    /register/facebook
  param:  { module: register, action: facebookRegister }
```

If I try to access this url, I get the following error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
An internal URI must contain a module and an action (module/action) ("" given).
```

Any advice would be much appreciated..
Thank you.

Comment: If you've got logging turned on, check what request info Symfony is getting. Also, make sure that a route higher up in routing.yml doesn't match the url you've entered and remember that accessing /register/facebook/ won't match the url that you've specified there.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the request info and eventually figured it out.. :) A link_to() wasn't set right.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to ensure that you have a Module and a Action created associated with your route.

In this case, you are specifying a "register" module, using a "facebookRegister" action.  In your application, under the Modules folder, ensure that you have a "Register" module.  If you do, ensure that you also have a executeFacebookRegister action in the associated Actions file.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was actually in the template ( facebookRegisterSuccess.php) in a link_to(). This is where the module/action wasn't set right..